Log4j2 not printing to console
`I am trying to use log4j2 but it is not printing to console anything :-
Following is the snippet of the class :-
public class apiaut {
public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(reRes.class);
public static final  String pathLog4j2 = System.getProperty("user.dir") +        "\\src\\test\\resources\\log4j2.xml";

static {
    // Initialize logger in a static block
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", pathLog4j2);
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Log4j2 initialized successfully.");

Dependency :-
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version> <!-- Replace "2.x.x" with the desired version -->
 </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
 </dependency>


log4j2.xml content stored in src/test/resources :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
     <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n"/>
     </Console>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
     <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>

log4j2 to print statements in console. I have checked  many solutions but none of them worked.
